# Loading an assembly with reflection fails with File is corrupt. HRESULT 0x8013110E because there are too many properties in the assembly?

Tags: c#, .net

We have an assembly which fails to load with reflection - it gives **File is corrupt. HRESULT 0x8013110E**
It does not matter how to load the assembly - could be `Assembly.LoadFile` or `Add-Type -Path` on the powershell console.

I am already trained to check for 32 vs 64 bits, but turns out this is not the case at all. What happens is that we have too many properties in the assembly. I am certain this is the cause, because removing any property (and building) solves the problem - the assembly can be loaded with reflection again.

I have examined the assembly with ildasm, observe:

```
C:\temp> ildasm.exe xyz.dll /stats /out=c:\temp\1.txt
C:\temp> cat C:\temp\1.txt | sls '\bFieldDef\b'

//   FieldDef      - 65534 (655340 bytes) 181 constant
```

Looks like a pretty clear 16 bits limit on FieldDef.

Is anyone aware of this? Is this documented anywhere? This is very unexpected - the code builds cleanly, but fails to load with reflection (we need it).

Comment: What is sls?  Did you open 1.txt to see contents?  sls looks like the Windows Update Utility from what I found on the web.

Comment: Old, but seems to point in your thought direction. "Offset & RID encoding" section of https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/anatomy-of-a-net-assembly-clr-metadata-2/. Should allow you to confirm the 2 byte size on your assembly. No idea if a switch is available somewhere when compiling.

Comment: @jdweng sls is alias for powershell command Select-String

Comment: No idea unless you are accidentally running Update utility instead of the Power Shell.